# Display drop-down caret button with "multiple" attribute in select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I'm using select2 plugin and I want to display drop-down carret button with the select menu element when "multiple" attribute is set.
How can I override the plugin's CSS?

Comment: yes its posible

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen how do we do that?

Comment: Where are you going to show caret? please see this http://jsfiddle.net/ishanbakshi/fyhsz9ra/ ,share a picture of what you want.